# Condição IF dentro de input

Tags: php, html

Código:

```
<input type="date" id="data" name="data" value="<?php echo $dataPost = $_GET['data'];  ?>" required>
```

A pergunta é a seguinte: Tem como fazer uma condição `if` antes do `value` dentro do `input` ?

Por exemplo:

```
if($x == $a){
    //mostra o value dentro do input igual acima.
}else{
    //mostra o value vazio.
}
```

Teria como fazer isso ? Ou de algum outro jeito ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dentro das tags `php` podes escrever código PHP. Nesse caso para ficar mais compacto podes usar um ternário:

```
value="<?php echo $dataPost = $x == $a ? $_GET['data'] : '';  ?>" required>
```

Neste exemplo ele cria um `if`, e caso verdadeiro dá o valor que está no `GET`, se der falso dá uma string vazia.

Comment: E se caso for falso e eu quiser por outro `GET` ?

Comment: @Kevin.F nesse caso em vêz de `''` podes colocar o que precisares.

Answer (score 1):

No caso seu *if* e *else* não temque ficar antes do value, ele pode ficar dentro do value, da seguinte forma:

```
<input type="date" id="data" name="data" value="<?php 

if($x == $a){
//mostra o value dentro do input igual acima.
   echo $_GET['data'];  
}
else{
//mostra o value vazio.
}

?>" required>
```

Conseguiu entender?? Se a comparação retornar TRUE no *if*, logo ele irá dar o echo da informação que você, e se der FALSE ele vai para o *else* que não tem echo nenhum, logo ele irá ficar em branco.

E não em necessidade de usar `$dataPost = $_GET['data'];` ou usa apenas o `$_GET['data'];` ou então define antes o `$dataPost = $_GET['data'];` e use apenas o `$dataPost;` no echo.

Mas acho que da forma que lhe passei vai ser melhor para você.

Testa e da um retorno aqui! :)